# UIView is non-interactive when added as subView of Main Window

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am adding a Mobclix ad to my app but want it to sit on top of table view.

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
[[windows objectAtIndex:0]  addSubview:mobclixView];
```

When I added it to the Window the UIView does not receive the touch events

If I add it as a subview of the main view it works fine

Update:

Tried this also, with no luck

[[windows objectAtIndex:0] insertSubview:mobclixView aboveSubview:self.tableView];

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
[[windows objectAtIndex:0]  insertSubview:mobclixView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding MobClix View Over UiView in which you have tableView instead of Main Window.

[self.view addSubview:mobClixView];